# i've been trying to save all edited under project paint in texture paint mode in blender but cant find the "save all edited" button

Tags: animation, textures, paint, blender, modeling

1. it's a text ,which i painted it's edges in texture paint mode.
2. After painting in texture paint mode,I cant find the save all edited button  under project paint as the video tutorial i'm watching shows.
3. I'm doing this in blender
4. Tried saving it normally but all progress is lost when i exit the app.
5. i was getting missing uv's,materials and texture before i started painting, under slots then painting mode I selected image and choose my colour. I'm suspecting that might be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Images that are edited within blender need to be manually saved separately from the main blender data. You can find the save image options in the [UV\Image editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/introduction.html).

Comment: i'm not allowed to post screen shots yet..I'm painting text edges in texture paint mode and based on the tutorial i'm watching,there should be a "save all edited" button under project paint @sambler

Comment: There is a [save all images](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/painting/texture_paint/slots_mask.html) under slots that will save changes, you still need to go into the uv image editor and save the image first before it will work.